# Mod_rewrite question mark not appearing in output url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to setup a simple mod_rewrite to redirect some open cart links which get broken when an import is done. Essentially the pretty urls for information pages don't go to where they should so im planning on overwriting them using .htaccess

Anyway I have a setup like so:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myshop.co.uk/
RewriteRule ^about-us/why-shop/?$  index.php?route=informationin/formation&information_id=7  [L]
```

So as I understand the following

```
www.myshop.co.uk/about-us/why-shop
```

will display the page contents of

```
index.php?route=information/information&information_id=7
```

However when I test this its only returning

```
www.myshop.co.uk/index.php
```

Everything after and including the ? appears to be ignored, first I thought I had to escape it but after reading various posts it doesn't seem like I need to.

Also while I'm here, is it possible to specify a RewriteBase which includes sub directories? For example

```
RewriteBase /development/myshop/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Everything after and including the ? appears to be ignored,

No that's correct it is appending full URL as per your rule. Only thing is that since you're not using `R` flag this redirection is happening silently.

If you add `R` flag in your rule then you'll notice full URL being displayed in your browser:

```
RewriteRule ^about-us/why-shop/?$  index.php?route=informationin/formation&information_id=7  [L,R]
```

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

Comment: Thanks! That was driving me a tad nuts.